# WPF video player with visual effects

Tags: audio, video, video-processing

My task is to develop a simple (since it's a training task) video player that would be able to apply *visual effects* to the video being currently played. I thought Aforge could do the job perfectly, but the problem is that it seems not to be supporting audio at all.

I'm completely new to media processing, therefore any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What particular visual effects you want to apply? Also, what is the OS you are targeting at?

Comment: @Anton: Have eventually found out that DirectShow.Net does provide all necessary facilities, although not as straightforward to implement as MediaElement component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I found this tutorial to be a good starting point.
http://www.informikon.com/directshow-tutorials/a-jukebox-sample-in-c-version-2.html

Hope this helps someone who might be experiencing similar problem.